# Searching through an ArrayList<Integer> inside of an ArrayList and comparing values

Tags: java, arraylist

So I have an `arrayList` that holds an `arraylist` with index values in it like this:

```
[[0,1,6],[3,5,7],[10,11]]
```

I need to find the shortest length from one of them to another. In this case it would be `6,7,10` and the length would be `three`.

The problem is that I don't know how to iterate when not all of the `arrayList` are the same size. Essentially I need to go through and compare each index to each index in each other array. So there would be `3*3*2` comparisons in this case. I just cannot figure out how to do so in java.

Does anyone know how I could iterate through this while comparing n `arrayList` with a different number of values in them?

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify your requirements please? "The shortest length from one of them to another"? I'm unsure where you've pulled those numbers from. I think clarifying your question will yield better answers, as a nested loop is a solution to the *XY Problem* you've presented.

Answer (score 0):

Although the spec is quite unclear I have written this code - not very elegant.

```
static void findShortest( List<List<Integer>> listOfLists ){
    int len = listOfLists.get(0).size();
    List<List<Integer>> oldlop = new ArrayList<>(len);
    List<Integer> olddist = new ArrayList<>(len);
    for( int i = 0; i < len; ++i ){
        oldlop.add( new ArrayList<Integer>() );
        olddist.add( 0 );
    }
    for( int j = 1; j < listOfLists.size(); ++j ){
        int newlen = listOfLists.get(j).size();
        List<List<Integer>> newlop = new ArrayList<>(newlen);
        List<Integer> newdist = new ArrayList<>(newlen);
        step( oldlop, olddist, 
              listOfLists.get(j-1), listOfLists.get(j),
              newlop, newdist );
        oldlop = newlop;
        olddist = newdist;
    }
    List<Integer> last = listOfLists.get( listOfLists.size()-1 );
    for( int k = 0; k < last.size(); ++k ){
        oldlop.get(k).add( last.get(k) );
    }
    System.out.println( oldlop );
    System.out.println( olddist );
}

static void step( List<List<Integer>> oldlop,
                  List<Integer> olddist,
                  List<Integer> frlist,
                  List<Integer> tolist,
                  List<List<Integer>> newlop,
                  List<Integer> newdist  ){
    for( int ito = 0; ito < tolist.size(); ++ito ){
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int minind = 0;
        List<Integer> minpath = null;
        newlop.add( new ArrayList<Integer>() );
        for( int ifr = 0; ifr < frlist.size(); ++ifr ){
            int tst = olddist.get(ifr) + 
                       Math.abs(tolist.get(ito)-frlist.get(ifr));
            if( tst < min ){
                min = tst;
                minind = frlist.get(ifr);
               minpath = oldlop.get(ifr);
            }
        }
        newlop.get(ito).addAll( minpath );
        newlop.get(ito).add( minind );
        newdist.add( min );
    }
}
```

Given a list of lists containing

```
[[0,1,6],[3,5,7],[10,11]]
```

the output is

```
[[6, 7, 10], [6, 7, 11]]
[4, 5]
```

with the accumulated "lengths" to the two indices in the last list ([10,11]) being [4,5]. The first is the minimum, and this selects the first list of collected index values: [6,7,10].

Answer (score 0):

this code gives you the minimum path length. In this case will be 13..

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Collections;

public class HelloWorld{

    public static void print(LinkedList<Integer> x){
        for(int i = 0; i<x.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(x.get(i));
        }

    }

    public static int sum(LinkedList<Integer> x){
        int acum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<x.size(); i++){
            acum+=x.get(i);
        }

        return acum;
    }

    public static LinkedList<Integer> permute(LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> array, int index, LinkedList<Integer> output, Integer flag, Integer aux, LinkedList<Integer> results){

    print(output);

    if(flag.equals(1)){
        aux = array.size();
        flag = 0;
    }

    if(output.size() == aux){
        int x = sum(output);
        results.add(x);
    }

    if(index == array.size()){

        Collections.sort(results);
        System.out.println("Final Shortest Path = " + results.get(0));
    }
    else{
        for(int i=0 ; i<array.get(index).size(); i++){
            output.add(array.get(index).get(i));
            permute(array,index+1,output, flag, aux, results);
            output.remove(output.size() - 1); 
        }
    }

    return output;
    }

     public static void main(String []args){
        LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> x = new LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>>();

        LinkedList<Integer> z1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        z1.add(0);
        z1.add(1);
        z1.add(6);

        LinkedList<Integer> z2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        z2.add(3);
        z2.add(5);
        z2.add(7);

        LinkedList<Integer> z3 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        z3.add(10);
        z3.add(11);

        x.add(z1);
        x.add(z2);
        x.add(z3);

        LinkedList<Integer> output = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        LinkedList<Integer> results = new LinkedList<Integer>();

        LinkedList<Integer> test = permute(x, 0, output, 1, 0, results);
        print(test);

     }
}
```